# Using ifelse statement to condense variables

Tags: r, if-statement

New to R, taking a very accelerated class with very minimal instruction.  So I apologize in advance if this is a rookie question.

The assignment I have is to take a specific column that has 21 levels from a dataframe, and condense them into 4 levels, using an if, or ifelse statement.  I've tried what feels like hundreds of combinations, but this is the code that seemed most promising:

```
> b2$LANDFORM=ifelse(b2$LANDFORM=="af","af_type",
        ifelse(b2$LANDFORM=="aflb","af_type",
        ifelse(b2$LANDFORM=="afub","af_type",
        ifelse(b2$LANDFORD=="afwb","af_type",
        ifelse(b2$LANDFORM=="afws","af_type",
        ifelse(b2$LANDFORM=="bfr","bf_type",
        ifelse(b2$LANDFORM=="bfrlb","bf_type",
        ifelse(b2$LANDFORM=="bfrwb","bf_type",
        ifelse(b2$LANDFORM=="bfrwbws","bf_type",
        ifelse(b2$LANDFORM=="bfrws","bf_type",
        ifelse(b2$LANDFORM=="lb","lb_type",
        ifelse(bs$LANDFORM=="lbaf","lb_type",
        ifelse(b2$LANDFORM=="lbub","lb_type",
        ifelse(b2$LANDFORM=="lbwb","lb_type","ws_type"))))))))))))))
```

LANDFORM is a factor, but I tried changing it to a character too, and the code still didn't work.

"ws_type" is the catch all for the remaining variables.

the code runs without errors, but when I check it, all I get is:

```
> unique(b2$LANDFORM)
```

[1] NA        "af_type"

Am I even on the right path?  Any suggestions?  Should I bite the bullet and make a new column with substr()?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: So essentially you want to re-level the column, it sounds like?  Is the column supposed to remain as a factor after the change? Have a look at `?levels` particularly the `levels<-` replacement function

Comment: Good lord. Also take a look at `%in%`.

Comment: @RichardScriven, levels looks promising.  Do you have any examples?  I checked the command out in the R manual, but the examples are pretty simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a great deal of experimenting, I consulted a co-worker, and he was able to simplify a huge amount of this.  Basically, I should have made a new column composed of the first two letters of the variables in LANDFORM, and then sample from that new column and replace values in LANDFORM, in order to make the ifelse() statement much shorter.  The code is:

```
> b2$index=as.factor(substring(b2$LANDFORM,1,2))
```

> b2$LANDFORM=ifelse(b2$index=="af","af_type",
>        ifelse(b2$index=="bf","bf_type",
>        ifelse(b2$index=="lb","lb_type",
>        ifelse(b2$index=="wb","wb_type",
>        ifelse(b2$index=="ws","ws_type","ub_type")))))
>
> b2$LANDFORM=as.factor(b2$LANDFORM)

Thanks to everyone who gave me some guidance!

Answer (score 1):

If your new levels are just the first two letters of the old ones followed by `_type` you can easily achieve what you want through:

```
     #prototype of your column
     mycol<-factor(sample(c("aflb","afub","afwb","afws","bfrlb","bfrwb","bfrws","lb","lbwb","lbws","wslb","wsub"), replace=TRUE, size=100))
     as.factor(paste(sep="",substr(mycol,1,2),"_type"))
```

Comment: The only problem is I can't do that for the "ws_type" variable, because it combines all remaining variables, including those that don't start with "ws".

ws-type is supposed to be a catch-all for "wb", "wblb", "wbub", "wbws", "ws", and "wslb".

That's why I thought the "ifelse" statement would work, since it ignores the letters and just forces the remaining variables to be "ws_type"

Comment: If it's just that the problem, you can try `mycol[mycol=="wb_type"]<-"ws_type"` after what I suggested.

Comment: I ran the code exactly as you showed, except I changed "mycol" to "b2$LANDFORM" and size=228 to match my data structure. b2$LANDFORM=factor(sample(c("af","aflb","afub","afwb","afws","bfrlb","bfrwb","bfrws","bfr","bfr","bfrwbws","lb","lbaf","lbub","lbwb","wslb","ws"),replace=TRUE,size=228))    
as.factor(paste(sep="",substr(b2$LANDFORM,1,2),"_type"))    
But when I check it with the head() command, the new LANDFORM variables don't match their "old" variables.  They don't even take the "_type" suffix, and there is no consistency.  "lb" got changed to "lbwb", "afwb", "af", "aflb" and more

Comment: Also, sorry for not including the code blocks.  Ctrl + k didn't work, and neither did 4 space...

Comment: Did you assign the result of the last line? I didn't include it in the asnwer (I thought it was obvious), but you need to `b2$LANDFORM<-as.factor(paste(sep="",substr(b2$LANDFORM,1,2),"_type")` to actually make the change. Edit the question if you still have troubles.

Comment: That does work for changing the variable names, but it does it randomly.  For instance, the original first 5 variables are "lb, lbaf, lb, lb, lb".  When I ran the code, they were renamed to "bf_type, lb_type, lb_type, bf_type, ws_type".  I reset everything, and re-ran the code, and it gave me another set of different random "xx_types".  Why won't it just read the first two letters, cut the rest, and then add "_type"?